# Use text elements to create custom CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, text, formatting

i'm pretty new to Python but i've been searching for this for a while and can't seem to find the answer in any way, i need this for a customer.
What i would like to do is the following:
i have a giant list of e-mail addresses and i would like to join them in a certain format into a CSV file.

So the list goes like this:
email@address.com,address@email.com,this@that.com,that@this.com,...

So what i would like to do is the following:
1) Trim everything for each e-mail address up until the @-symbol and put that into a variable (let's call this one "name").
2) Next i would like the whole e-mailaddress to go into a different variable (let's call this one "e-mail")
3) Then i would like to print it out in a format like:
name,email,name,e-mail,name,email,... so i can use it as a valid csv with name and e-mailaddress.

I would post the code i already have, but i don't think it's going to help much :)
Thanks in advance for helping out!

EDIT:
I forgot to mention the list from which i'm pulling the e-mail addresses is in a csv file. See my code below.

```
    import csv
writefile = open('output.txt', mode='w')
tempwrite = []
with open('emailadresseninkomma.csv') as csvfile:
    readfile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readfile:
         tempwrite.append(row)

with open('output.txt', mode='w') as out_csv:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_csv, fieldnames=['Name', 'Email'])
    #Comment this out if you don't want a header row
    writer.writeheader()    
    for e in tempwrite:
        writer.writerow({'Name':e.split('@')[0], 'Email': e})
```

I get this error message:

```
line 14, in <module>
    writer.writerow({'Name':e.split('@')[0], 'Email': e})
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I'm positively doing something wrong on creating the list from the already existing csv file from which i read. Again, thanks for al the help. :)

Comment: It's easier to help if you post your code

Comment: Do you want some new lines in your csv file? Is the input really a `list`, or a string or from another csv file? Do you want `email@address.com` to output `email,email@address.com` followed by a new line?

Comment: Why do you want the output to be a single line? It would be more usual to put each (name, email) pair on a separate line.

Comment: What does `tempwrite` contain after you append rows to it? is it `['email1@example.com','email2@example.com',...]`?

Comment: Ok, your issue is that `row` will be a list. So currently `tempwrite` is a list of lists. If you just want to add the email to `tempwrite` then you will need to add the element of row which contains the email address. Assuming that your 'emailadresseninkomma.csv' file is actually just a single column then this would be `row[0]`, so try `tempwrite.append(row[0])`

Comment: @solarc yes, the `tempwrite` does contain `['email1@example.com','email2@example.com',...]`
@PerlPingu yes, `tempwrite.append(row[0])` does work, but it only shows me the first e-mail address. Is there a possibility i can make it work with all of them?

Comment: If `print(tempwrite)` actually gives `['email1@example.com','email2@example.com',...]` then you shouldn't be getting the error in the first place. Can you try `print(e)` and `type(e)` in your `for e in tempwrite` loop and post the output here please

Comment: So the output with `print(e)` is `['email1@domain1.com', 'email2@domain2.com', 'email3@domain3.com', ...]` and `type(e)` gives me no visible output, so i threw it in an if statement like this: `if type(e) == list:
              print('True')` and the output was `True` , meaning `e` is a list (which i assume you wanted to know. :)

Comment: See my updated answer for possible solutions

Comment: That did the trick, thank you so much! I will look at the code and learn from it for future projects. I've got a feeling this python journey is starting to get more fun, though it's not very easy in the beginning i must say :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so assuming that you actually want each (name, email) pair on a new line:

```
import csv
outfile = 'your/output/file'
with open(outfile, 'w') as out_csv:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_csv, fieldnames=['Name', 'Email'])
    #Comment this out if you don't want a header row
    writer.writeheader()    

    emaillist =
 ['email@address.com','address@email.com','this@that.com','that@this.com']

    for e in emaillist:
        writer.writerow({'Name':e.split('@')[0], 'Email': e})
```

**UPDATED**: Following the discussion in the comments I think that I have a solution to your problem, which I believe is caused by your `'emailadresseninkomma.csv'` file not having any newlines and just being a single comma-separated string.

Solution: use `extend` instead of `append`. This will unlist `row` if it is a list. However, if your file *might* contain newlines and thus `row` *might* be a string, then you will need to test if that is the case. The code below assumes you're using Python 3.

```
import csv
writefile = open('output.txt', mode='w')
tempwrite = []
with open('emailadresseninkomma.csv') as csvfile:
    readfile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readfile:
        if isinstance(row, str):
            tempwrite.append(row)
        elif isinstance(row, (list, set, tuple)):
            tempwrite.extend(row)
        else:
            print('Row contains: {} | Not a list, tuple, set, or string, not added to tempwrite').format(row)

with open('output.txt', mode='w') as out_csv:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_csv, fieldnames=['Name', 'Email'])
    #Comment this out if you don't want a header row
    writer.writeheader()    
    for e in tempwrite:
        writer.writerow({'Name':e.split('@')[0], 'Email': e})
```

Comment: So i had the CSV part already, but i was struggling with the '@' split part, i'm trying it tonight and i will keep you posted! Thanks already :)

Comment: Just a word of warning. Parsing email addresses is a somewhat tricky business and in fact that split will technically not work for emails containing an escaped ‘@‘ in the name part. Check out: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/

Comment: Tried the code but failed. Edit is in OP, thanks again for the help.

Comment: The edited answer above does the trick right away. Thanks again! :)